# Is the memory that used by UserControl stores in Heap?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, memory-management, heap-memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fields of class, are they stored in the stack or heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565331/fields-of-class-are-they-stored-in-the-stack-or-heap)

I was reading some article about Stack vs Heap (just to refresh my knowledge).

Far as I know, if I create a value type inside a reference type (a class), the value type will also be stored in the Heap.  Because where the value type being store is depends on where its created.

But then, when we create our application (say WPF/Silverlight), when we create our UserControl, ViewModel, isn't they are also a class (an object) a reference type?

So I kind of wonder, so no matter what I creates inside the UserControl and ViewModel will also be in Heap?

Comment: Only value types can be stored on the stack. Since the objects you mention aren't value types, they will always be stored on the heap.

Comment: Who even cares? You should not mind such implementation details anyway...

Comment: @H.B. I just kind of throught of the interview question I got ask before about Heap vs Stack... I really wonder why people will ask that...

Comment: @KingChan I think the best answer to any interview question about stack vs. heap, if it's for a .NET job, is to discuss why it doesn't matter, and the real issue is copy semantics.  That really shows you know what you're talking about, since stack and heap don't matter for .NET.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Ahh, I see... All I answered last time was just explain how/when/where they store it last time.  Thanks.

Comment: @KingChan Just realize, too, that many **interviewers** don't know that it's a bad question, and will argue with you.  That's probably a bad sign about the job, though ;)

Comment: [Heap and stack from programming perspective](http://www.maxi-pedia.com/what+is+heap+and+stack) It's explained very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I kind of wonder, so no matter what I creates inside the UserControl and ViewModel will also be in Heap?

Yes, this is true.  The `UserControl` is a class, so the memory for it, and any variables within it, it will be stored on the heap.

There are two things here:

1. This is purely an implementation detail.  It doesn't/shouldn't really matter where the memory is stored.  The usage semantics are all that really matter (ie: passing into a method just copies the reference, not the entire object, etc)
2. The variable values may get copied into the stack as you use them.  For details, see this (very detailed) [answer by Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2561622/65358) detailing what happens with fields stored within a class.

Comment: That's really detail lol  Now I wonder when will we ever stores things in Stack... I mean like almost every desktop application has to create a (Form/UserControl) and do things inside, so is like everything is in heap...

Comment: @KingChan It's better to not think about stack and heap at all - but yes, in general, most memory usage is in the heap.  The stack, by default, will only be 1mb - but most programs use far more than 1mb of ram :)

Comment: @KingChan When you're really *storing* data, it's almost always on the heap (which is why the heap is rather large and that stack quite small).  Most of what the stack has are short lived local variables.  You will create *lots* of them in almost every program you make.  If nothing else, the stack will have lots of references to storage locations on the heap in your programs.

Comment: Little shame that I just learnt Stack is 1mb by default :)

Comment: @KingChan It's configurable - and even smaller in asp.net (256kb by default)... Each thread gets its own stack allocation of that amount.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the class for the UserControl, and all the property values it contains (even though many of those are value types), will be stored on the heap.

Don't worry too much about stack vs heap. It's usually sufficient to know the following:

- objects stored on the stack (including references to objects on the heap, which are IntPtr value types) are limited in scope and lifetime to the layer of the call stack for which the stack frame was created.
- objects stored on the heap are limited in scope and lifetime to that of any reference to that object on the stack or heap.

Now go code :)